# Bootstrap + AngularJS - Multiple page print job with common header/footer

Tags: angularjs, printing, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap with AngularJS and trying to `ng-repeat` out a table within the template I purchased and when over a certain amount is put into the `orderInformation.items` array I run into issues with how the print looks.

I want to be able to hit print and have a defined page heading and a defined page footer that will not change and should nest in the top and bottom of the print preview across all pages. The only content that will change is the items that AngularJS is doing an `ng-repeat` on.

How can this be done? I've been searching for days and days and nothing out there seems to work.

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 card-box">
       <table id="invoice-contents" style="width: 100%">
          <thead>
           <!-- This is where logo, company details, barcode go -->
           </thead>
           <tbody>
             <table id="item-table" class="table m-t-30" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1)">
               <thead>
                 <!-- Invoice Item headers -->
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                  <tr ng-repeat="item in orderInformation.items">
                    <td style="text-align: center">{{$index + 1}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">{{item.qty.ordered}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">{{item.qty.shipped}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">{{item.qty.backordered}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">{{item.binLocation}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">{{item.partNumber}} - {{item.description}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">{{item.price.current * item.qty.shipped | number: 2}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right">{{item.price.extended * item.qty.shipped | number: 2}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </tbody>
         <tfoot>
            <!-- Special order notes, totals, taxes, terms -->
         </tfoot>
       </table>
     </div>
   </div> <!-- end container -->
```

This doesn't work when I use the recommended CSS that I have found around:

```
  thead { display: table-header-group; }
  tbody { display: table-row-group; }
  tfoot { display: table-footer-group; }
```

The documentation says a table can't have two `thead` so I know the problem lies there, but I can't find any other way to get a block to print top and bottom on all pages other than `table-header-group`.

Answer (score 0):

A way round this through much trial and error was to product an onscreen display of a single invoice page with how ever many rows of data and then use `display:none` to hide a view that would only show during print with CSS `@media print`. I had to calculate how many rows would show on each page and use `.splice()` and nested ng-repeats to get it displaying properly.